# How to get CA certificate bundle to single file using script?

Tags: powershell, certificate, openssl, windows-server-2012-r2

I believe I can get a bundle certificate export doing the following manual steps:

- Run `certmgr.msc`
- Select all wanted certificates and go right-click and select all
  tasks -> export:

[image]

then:

[image]

then:

[image]

then:

[image]

then:

[image]

then:

[image]

then:

[image]

[image]

How can I do this with a *script*, perhaps with PowerShell or openssl?

I am trying to get the file particularly for the [cacertfile of this guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#enabling-tls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command should get you what you're after:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\CurrentUser\Root | Select -Unique | Export-Certificate -FilePath c:\allcerts.p7b -Type P7B
```